# Infinite loop of startup repair

Tags: windows-7, boot, 32-bit, bootrepair, infinite-loop

I have windows 7 on an old laptop which was working fine till this morning when it, out of nowhere is not booting up and keep redirecting me to startup repair.
It has been running this repair for 3 hours now and still has not started.
[image]
The laptop is a 32-bit dell Inspiron 1525.

Edit: I ran a full diagnostics, this error appeared.
[image]

Comment: I think it most likely to be a hard drive problem. Get Dell's hardware test application on a bootable USB Key and test the hardware, especially the drive.

Comment: Startup repair may sometimes get stuck. Try turning it off and on and see if you get past. Also try restoring to a previous restore point or boot into safe mode

Comment: @John not necessarily. If a file is written to the harddisk when power runs out, or a BSoD occurs during a write, the same can happen.

Comment: I merely suggested "maybe" so then remove the drive, put in a carrier and see if you can read it (and recover data from it).

Comment: @LPChip I have tried it like three times, hence this once I thought to let it run and went for a nap. It still didn't finish.

Comment: @John I ran a diagnostic and added the results in the question as an edit. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: The hard drive has failed - that is displayed in the test results. Is it worth replacing the drive?

Comment: @John I am not willing to spend much on this old laptop, I just got it out to test if it was working(Which it was since around 4 days) and now this. Is this a hardware problem or can I just format the drive and put a light linux distro?

Comment: You can try formatting, but I think it will fail doing that. You can only try.

Comment: @John I tried to run a live os using a USB. I am having trouble mounting only one of the partition, apparently, the C:/ drive. I am able to access the contents of the rest. What should I do?

Comment: Try recovering what you can. If you do not wish to repair the machine, then you can only recover what you can and then use it in a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

A PSA diagnostic code of 2000-0142 indicates the the HDD (hard drive) Self Test was unsuccessful. It could be the HDD, HDD cable, or connector on the motherboard. Open the system, re-seat the HDD and HDD cable. Run the PSA test again.

If it fails again replace the drive.